# Get object reference of UIViewController using rootViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I need to access an object that it's present in many UIViewControllers from AppDelegate class. I want to update the top bar icon when a notification is received. What I have done so far:

```
UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;
```

If I had only one UIViewController then I would just cast the vc to my UIViewController and get the object. But the problem is that I have many UIViewControllers and I don't know which one will be active when I need it.

The object inside the UIViewControllers that I need it's called topBarManager. How can I access that object from AppDelegate? Thanks

**EDIT:**
*One way to solve this is by using `isKindOfClass` but I need to write all the cases for all the UIViewControllers.*

Comment: Why does the AppDelegate need to get involved?  Can't you arrange for notifications or something so the correct view controller  can do this work autonomously?

Comment: No, it has to be inside AppDelegate.

Comment: Nah, that smells wrong.  Anyway good luck!